# How to pass a query param in post call in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to reactjs.I am doing a post call but not sure, how to pass a boolean value in url as a query param in reactjs. For eg: http://www.abx.com?example=true. How do I pass this example in post api call.
Endpoint: `API_SAMPLE: "/sample",`

post call:

```
postCall() {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    const data = {
      product: {
        body
      },

    };
    return http
      .post(this.API.API_SAMPLE, data, config)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  }
```

i want to add a boolean value in my query param, how will i do that

Comment: Umm. Type in into the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use template literals to pass the variable to your URL.

```js
const example = true;
const url = `http://abx.com/sample?example=${example}`
```

or use it this way:

```js
return http.post(`${this.API.API_SAMPLE}?example=${example}`, data, config) {...}
```

Comment: i have updated my question, Can you plz have a look how I'll be do it in my case

Comment: Replace `this.API.API_SAMPLE` with `url` variable that you create as I showed you

Comment: is there any way to add this query param in endpoint: API_SAMPLE: "/sample"

Answer (score 1):

wether you are using POST or GET you will have to modify the URL.
You can do this "dynamically" or you can use something like URLSearchParams:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

```
var URL = "http://example.com/search";
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(URL);

searchParams.append("example", "true");

searchParams.toString() // "http://example.com/search?example=true";
```

Just make sure you support the correct browsers:
https://caniuse.com/#search=urlsearchparams